# Swift Package manifest property 'defaultLocalization' not set

Tags: swift, xcode, localization, swift-package-manager, localizable.strings

Experimenting with Swift Packages, I created a new package. Source files and resources from an existing Xcode project framework target were moved over into the new structure.

Attempting to build, the transcript shows an error:

```
manifest property 'defaultLocalization' not set; it is required in the presence of localized resources
```

How can this be solved so I can create a Swift package?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is explained in [WWDC2020 session 10169](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10169/).

At around eleven and a half minutes into the video, Anders Bertelrud, Apple engineer Developer Tools introduces the topic. An example is shown using Xcode 12 to add a default localisation parameter to the package manifest.

> This declares the language I'm using during development and will be
> used as the fallback localization at runtime if no better match is
> available. This is needed for any package that contains resources.

An example manifest including the `defaultLocalization` parameter can be seen as follows:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackageUI",
    defaultLocalization: "en",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyPackageUI",
            targets: ["MyPackageUI"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyPackageUI",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyPackageUITests",
            dependencies: ["MyPackageUI"]),
   ]
)
```